# The use of "proceed" on the web

Tags: british-english, internet

Recently I have been puzzled why the word `proceed` is found on most websites when the user is going to *checkout*, *cart* or *shopping cart*.

Is there a reason for this in the english language that warrants the use of `proceed` or can I just use `go to`.

Answer (score 2):

"**proceed**" is different to "go to" because it means movement along a proscribed path, like moving to the next step in a N-step **process**.

This makes it a better choice of word for when the user is moving through the process of registering, or buying an item, each of which is a multi-stage process.  "Go to" suggests that you might leave this multi-stage process and go somewhere completely different, possibly losing your **progress**.

You can probably feel the connection between the words "progress", "proceed", and "process" by this point.  They are all related from the same latin roots.

Comment: Just to amplify: both "Proceed" and "Go to" are appropriate labels for buttons - BUT for different purposes.

Comment: @TrevorD true.  I assumed, reading the question, that "Proceed" appeared when the user was already part-way through the purchase process, but on re-reading it doesn't actually state that.

Comment: You would be correct. The UI will highlight a `proceed` when something is added to the cart so would be part way.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I knew what you meant and wasn't intending to crticise your answer at all.  I just wanted to ensure that OP was clear that both are acceptable - indeed, appropriate - in different circumstances.